# Jest.js and Create-react-app: I get "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when running test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, create-react-app

My code

**App.test.js**

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";

let result = moment().format();


describe("anything",()=>{
    it("should return a fail..or at least something",()=>{
        expect(result).toBe("wrong")
    })
})
```

I run:

**npx jest** or **yarn test** or **npm test**

I get:

```
npx jest
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/wktdev/Desktop/thing/workflow_magic_guest_app/src/App.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import moment from "moment-timezone";
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.586s
Ran all test suites.
```

It looks like it is similar to this: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9292

When I do npm ls jest it says there are missing dependencies. When II try to manually install them they don't install and the problem is not fixed.

```
UNMET DEPENDENCY react-scripts@2.1.5
  └── UNMET DEPENDENCY jest@23.6.0
```

Comment: what happens if you run `npm test` or `yarn test`

Comment: @Teneff Yes it works. God dammit. lol

Comment: The instance I had was working and I cloned a new instance and it doesn't work now. When I do  npm ls jest  it says there are missing dependencies. When I try to manually install them it doesn't work. I will edit the query to reflect this.

Comment: Did you installed the listed dependencies with "npm install" after cloning the repo?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out per a message that jest outputs. There are instructions that jest gives to remove the package.lock file, yarn.lock and reinstall via yarn install.
I tried it before and I thought that it didn't work and only removed jest, but I was wrong. It seems to work - for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you add jest manually, remove jest dependency from `package.json` and run `npm install` or `yarn install`.

or you can run `npm test` or `yarn test` to check the instruction.

Answer (score -4):

To fix that do you need create the file: `./__tests__/setup.js` and put that:

```js
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

After that you only need run: `npm run test`

Comment: Doesn't help at all